# How to seed the firestore database after deployment?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase for a API only project, for initial setup, I need to seed the firestore database with some users and basic data.

How can we run this?

One thought would be to make an endpoint /setup?someKey=someValue and pass in the data. Is there a better more proper way of seeding the database with initial values?

Also I would also needs to create a super user inside the Firebase Auth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy way is to use the Admin SDK from you own machine.

You create a JS file which starts with

```
#!/usr/bin/node
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert("xxxx.json")
});
```

where `xxxx.json` is a private key file for your Firebase service account. You can get this file from the Firebase console as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?authuser=0#initialize-sdk) in the doc. One usually stores it in the `functions` folder at the same level than the `index.js` file. If you want to store it somewhere else in the `functions` folder (e.g. in a sub-folder) you need to adapt the path in the above code.

Then, in the rest of the file you can interact with your Firestore instance exactly as you would do in a Cloud Function, e.g:

```
admin.firestore().collection('...').add({...});
```

Depending on how your data is formatted you have to write the code to create the documents in Firestore.

For, example let's imagine your have your data as an array of JS Objects. You could do as follows:

```
const myArrayOfObjects = [{color: 'blue', quantity: 34}, {color: 'green', quantity: 98}];

const p = [];
myArrayOfObjects.forEach(obj => {
    p.push(admin.firestore().collection('...').add(obj)
})
Promise.all(p);
```

Then you just execute this js file by doing `node thefilename.js` in a terminal window